# Register Oracle Out Parameters with SQL Alchemy in a Scoped Session safe way for use with Cherrypy Tools/Plugins

Tags: python, oracle, multithreading, sqlalchemy, cherrypy

I've been chasing this issue for months now. The closest post I could find on my issue is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499537/cherrypy-random-requests-hanging-then-server-becomes-unresponsive/42197639#comment130911503_42197639)

I'm really trying to avoid the "XY" problem with this post. But it's hard to even know what the X is.

### My Setup

I have a webpage that uses AJAX to query a Cherrypy REST API I made with a connection pool using SQLAlchemy to Oracle (cx_Oracle). I use the code recipe [found here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200519135612/http://www.defuze.org/archives/222-integrating-sqlalchemy-into-a-cherrypy-application.html) for my cherrypy/sqlalchemy connection pool.

### Expected Results

Send request to API endpoint, get userdata back without a 502 error/timeout from Cherrypy.

### What Happens

When I send 10 queries (for example, it happens at all #s of queries) in a Promise.all (JavaScript) to the webserver on average 9 will return, one or more queries will hang, then reach my webproxy's 10s timeout and fail with a 502. I then have JavaScript set to *retry* if a 502 is received and it immediately works on the exact same query.

When I restart cherrypy's server, at first it seems to run fine.

The other kicker here, potentially, is that I am using stored proceedures and functions in this call. I questioned if somehow using these cursors/connections were not closed properly within the scoped_session object?

Looking for any clues you might have as to why this is happening or how I can troubleshoot the issue

```
raw_conn = None
#print('units', data['units'], dir(data['units']))
#print(data['units'])
try:
    # Give it some user id, this is just example code
    data["name"] = cherrypy.request.db.query(func.user_package.get_users_function(data['uid'], 'US')).one()[0]
    raw_conn = cherrypy.request.db.connection().engine.raw_connection()
    cur = None
    data["metadata"] = []
    try:
        cur = raw_conn.cursor()
        # I tried this below, same results as the above line
        #data["units"] = cur.callfunc('user_package.get_users_function', str, [data['uid'], 'US'])
        result = cur.var(cx_Oracle.CURSOR)
        #cur.callfunc('cwms_ts.retrieve_ts', None, [result, data['ts'], data["units"], data["start_time"].strftime('%d-%b-%Y %H%M'), data["end_time"].strftime('%d-%b-%Y %H%M')])
        cur.execute('''begin
            users_metadata.getUserInfo(
            :1,
            :2,
            :3,
            to_date(:4, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24mi'),
            to_date(:5, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24mi'),
            'CDT');
        end;''', (result, data['uid'], data["name"], data["start_time"].strftime(
            '%d-%b-%Y %H%M'), data["end_time"].strftime('%d-%b-%Y %H%M')))
        # Data is returned as a 2d array with [datetime, int, int]
        data['values'] = [[x[0].isoformat(), x[1] if not isinstance(
            x[1], float) else round(x[1], 2), x[2]] for x in result.values[0].fetchall()]
    finally:
        if cur:
            cur.close()
        #return data
    data["end_time"] = data["end_time"].isoformat()
    data["start_time"] = data["start_time"].isoformat()
    return data
except Exception as err:
    # Don't log this error
    return {"title": "Failed to Query User Date", "msg": str(err), "err": "User Error"}
finally:
    if raw_conn: raw_conn.close()
```

Here's my server.conf file for Cherrypy

```
[/]
cors.expose.on = True
tools.sessions.on = True
tools.gzip.on = True
tools.gzip.mime_types = ["text/plain", "text/html", "application/json"]
tools.sessions.timeout = 300
tools.db.on = True
tools.secureheaders.on = True
log.access_file = './logs/access.log'
log.error_file = './logs/application.log'
tools.staticdir.root: os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = '.'
tools.proxy.on = True

[/static]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "./public"

[/favicon.ico]
tools.staticfile.on = True
tools.staticfile.filename = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) + "/public/terminal.ico"
```

Here's the stuff I have setup different from the code recipe linked above

```
    def start(self):
        if not self.sa_engine: 
            self.sa_engine = create_engine(
                self.dburi, echo=False, pool_recycle=7199,
                pool_size=300, max_overflow=100, pool_timeout=9)  # , pool_pre_ping=True)
            cherrypy.log("Connected to Oracle")
```

Apache Config

```
<Location /myapp>
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080
  ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Posting this here if you stumble on my post with a similar issue!**

With all gateway error's you question if it's the gateway and not the server itself.

In my post I questioned the server (CherryPy). This was because our apache server/proxy has a 10 second timeout. Every other query was making it, but for some reason one or two queries would hang.

I even went about creating a python test script to send async requests to the API (cherrypy) directly via IP address and bypass the Reverse Proxy. This worked flawless for 1000+ connections (10-20 at a time) over 15 seconds for the same query and did not have any 502's.

But doing the same test through the reverse proxy failed (Lots of 502's), so I knew it must have to do with apache itself.

The resolution I was able to come up with this was to add the following to my Apache config.
I read in one place (Apache docs) that `Keepalive=On` will help maintain a connection over firewalls, and that `timeout=##` can be used at the location level so that it does not override our existing global `timeout=10`

We want to maintain that 10 second timeout if the other location tags/apps do misbehave.

I still do not know what causes 1 or 2 of my queries to occasionally get a 502. But extending my timeout on the proxypass line has all but fixed this. It still happens but is WAY less frequent now.

The final replaced block is:

```
<Location /myapp>
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080 retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=30 Keepalive=On
  ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
</Location>
```

And just as a side note, these requests that are able to finish beyond the 10 second timeout now show `Stalled: 10.29 s` in the network tab. `Queueing: 1.13 ms`